# Identifying rows with uniform sequence while ignoring missing data in R

Tags: r, count, sequence

I'm working with panel data where the same variable is recorded multiple times to create a sequence of states. I only want to use observations that do not have uniform sequences but I am struggling to create a flag that would identify these while also not considering NAs as a different state.

I've created an example dataset to make things simple:

```
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
S1 <- c("Education", "Employment", "Education", "Education", "Education", "Education", "Education", "Education", "Education", "Education")
S2 <- c("Education", "Employment", "Education", "Unemployed", "Education", "Education", "Employment", "Education", "Education", "Education")
S3 <- c("Education", "Employment", "NA", "Unemployed", "Education", "Employment", "Employment", "NA", "Education", "Education")
S4 <- c("Education", "Employment", "Education", "Unemployed", "Education", "Employment", "Employment", "NA", "Education", "Education")
S5 <- c("Education", "Employment", "Education", "Unemployed", "Education", "Employment", "Employment", "NA", "Education", "Education")
df <- data.frame(ID, S1, S2, S3, S4, S5)
df

   ID         S1         S2         S3         S4         S5
1   1  Education  Education  Education  Education  Education
2   2 Employment Employment Employment Employment Employment
3   3  Education  Education         NA  Education  Education
4   4  Education Unemployed Unemployed Unemployed Unemployed
5   5  Education  Education  Education  Education  Education
6   6  Education  Education Employment Employment Employment
7   7  Education Employment Employment Employment Employment
8   8  Education  Education         NA         NA         NA
9   9  Education  Education  Education  Education  Education
10 10  Education  Education  Education  Education  Education
```

I'd ideally be able to flag or keep only observations ID=c("4", "6", "7").

I tried couple of approaches:

I tried counting the consecutive states but that doesn't account for the separate IDs

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df_long)
df_long[, employed := (S=="Employment")
   ][, e.length := with(rle(employed), rep(lengths,lengths))
     ][employed == 0, e.length := 0]

df_long[, education := (S=="Education")
        ][, edu.length := with(rle(education), rep(lengths,lengths))
          ][education == 0, edu.length := 0]
df_long
```

I've also tried manually creating a flag variable but that doesn't account for NAs and with the number of repeated observations in my dataset it is too manual/time-consuming

```
df$employed[df$S1=="Education" & df$S2=="Education" & df$S3=="Education" & df$S4=="Education" & df$S5=="Education"] <- 1
df$employed
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could also vectorize as follows `which(rowSums((df[, 2] == df[, -(1:2)]) + (df[, -(1:2)] == "NA")) < 4)` (but only if you create your data while specifying `, stringsAsFactors = FALSE`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its super easy:

```
df[df == "NA"] <- NA

df$keep <- lengths(apply(df[,-1],1, table)) > 1
```

---

```
#> which(df$keep)
#[1] 4 6 7
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar solution, but without `table`:

```
df[df == "NA"] <- NA
df$to.keep <- apply(df[, -1], 1, function(x) {
  !any(is.na(x)) & length(unique(x)) > 1
})

> which(df$to.keep)
[1] 4 6 7
```

Comment: please add `S6 <- c("Education", "Employment", "Education", "Unemployed", "Education", "Employment", "Employment", "EMP", "Education", "Education")
` to the data.frame. You will see **"your solution"** will not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
S1 <- c("Education", "Employment", "Education", "Education", "Education", "Education", "Education", "Education", "Education", "Education")
S2 <- c("Education", "Employment", "Education", "Unemployed", "Education", "Education", "Employment", "Education", "Education", "Education")
S3 <- c("Education", "Employment", "NA", "Unemployed", "Education", "Employment", "Employment", "NA", "Education", "Education")
S4 <- c("Education", "Employment", "Education", "Unemployed", "Education", "Employment", "Employment", "NA", "Education", "Education")
S5 <- c("Education", "Employment", "Education", "Unemployed", "Education", "Employment", "Employment", "NA", "Education", "Education")
S6 <- c("Education", "Employment", "Education", "Unemployed", "Education", "Employment", "Employment", "EMP", "Education", "Education")
df <- data.frame(ID, S1, S2, S3, S4, S5,S6)
```

## Added S6 also from your comments where Andre answer not able to label it correctly

```
library(dplyr)
df[df == "NA"] <- NA

df$Flag_NA = ifelse(apply(df %>% select(-ID),1,function(x) any(is.na(x))),'No','Yes')
df$Flag_Uniform = ifelse(apply(df %>% select(-ID,-Flag_NA), 1, function(x)length(unique(x))) == 1,'No','Yes')
df = df %>% mutate(Flag_keep = ifelse(Flag_NA == Flag_Uniform,"Yes","No"))

df
   ID         S1         S2         S3         S4         S5         S6 Flag_NA Flag_Uniform Flag_keep
1   1  Education  Education  Education  Education  Education  Education     Yes           No        No
2   2 Employment Employment Employment Employment Employment Employment     Yes           No        No
3   3  Education  Education       <NA>  Education  Education  Education      No          Yes        No
4   4  Education Unemployed Unemployed Unemployed Unemployed Unemployed     Yes          Yes       Yes
5   5  Education  Education  Education  Education  Education  Education     Yes           No        No
6   6  Education  Education Employment Employment Employment Employment     Yes          Yes       Yes
7   7  Education Employment Employment Employment Employment Employment     Yes          Yes       Yes
8   8  Education  Education       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>        EMP      No          Yes        No
9   9  Education  Education  Education  Education  Education  Education     Yes           No        No
10 10  Education  Education  Education  Education  Education  Education     Yes           No        No
```